# Why is it the programmer’s responsibility to call things on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

Why is it the responsibility of the programmer to call UI related methods on the main thread with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {}
```

Theoretically, couldn’t this be left up to the compiler or some other agent to determine?

Comment: Theoretically, if the developers of UIKit had nothing better to do.

Comment: i put proper explanation in my answer. check it and follow it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual answer is developer inertia and grandfathering.

The Cocoa UI API is huge—nay, gigantic. It has also been in continuous development since the 1990's.

Back when I was a youth and there were no multi-core, 64-bit, anything, 99.999% of all applications ran on the main thread. Period. (The original Mac OS, pre-OS X, didn't even have threads.)

Later, a few specialized tasks could be run on background threads, but largely apps still ran on the main thread.

Fast forward to today where it's trivial to dispatch thousands of tasks for background execution and CPUs can run 30 or more current threads, it's easy to say "hey, why doesn't the compiler/API/OS handle this main-thread thing for me?" But what's nigh on impossible is re-engineering four decades of Cocoa code and apps to make that work.

There are—I'm going to say—hundreds of millions of lines of code that all assume UI calls are executing concurrently on the main thread. As others have pointed out, there is no cleaver switch or pre-processor that's going to undo all of those assumptions, fix all of those potential deadlocks, etc.

(Heck, if the compiler could figure this kind of stuff out we wouldn't even have to write multi-threaded code; you'd just let the compiler slice up your code so it runs concurrently.)

Finally, such a change just isn't worth the effort. I do Cocoa development full time and the number of times I have to deal with the "update control from a background thread problem" occurs, at most, once a week or so. There's no development cost-benefit analysis that's going to dedicate a million man-hours to solving a problem that already has a straight forward solution.

Now if you were developing a new, modern, UI API from scratch, you'd simply make the entire UI framework thread safe and whole question goes away. And maybe Apple has a brand new, redesigned-from-the-ground-up, UI framework in a lab somewhere that does that. But that's the only way I see something like this happening.

Comment: Thank your historical perspective on this. I appreciated reading through that and it makes a lot of sense given that context. Perhaps this brand new framework you dream of is SwiftUI but I’m unsure if SwiftUI does this or not.

Answer (score 1):

You would be substituting one kind of frustration for another.

Suppose that all UI-related methods that require invocation on the main thread did so by:

- using `DispatchQueue.main.async`: You would be hiding asynchronous behaviour, with no obvious way to "follow up" on the result. Code like this would now fail:

  ```
  label.text = "new value"
  assert(label.text == "new value")
  ```

  You would have thought that the property `text` just harmlessly assigned some value. In fact, it enqueued a work item to asynchronously execute on the main thread. In doing so, you've broken the expectation that your system has reached its desired state by the time you've completed that line.
- using `DispatchQueue.main.sync`: You would be hiding a potential for deadlock. Synchronous code on the `main` queue can be very dangerous, because it's easy to unintentionally block (on the main thread) yourself waiting for such work, causing deadlock.

I think one way this could have been achieved is by having a hidden thread dedicated to UI. All UI-related APIs would switch to that thread to do their work. Though I don't know how expensive that would be (each switch to that thread is probably no faster than waiting on a lock), and I could imagine there's lots of "fun" ways that'll get you to write deadlocking code.

Answer (score -2):

Only on rare instances would the UI call anything in the main thread, except for user login timeouts for security.  Most UI related methods for any particular window are called within the thread that was started when the window was initialized.
I would rather manage my UI calls instead of the compiler because as a developer, I want control and do not want to rely on third party 'black boxes'.

Answer (score -2):

check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/main_thread_checker

and **UPDATE UI FROM MAIN THREAD ONLY**!!!